# Run file after file download complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, download, node-webkit

I am very new to node-webkit. I am using the following code to download a file. How would I go about running the file automatically when the file has finished?

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("update_setup.exe");
var request = https.get(url + "/appdata/update_setup.exe", function (response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use the writable stream's `close` event and spawn a child process. The event will fire once the response has completed piping to the stream.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var file = fs.createWriteStream('update_setup.exe');
var request = https.get(path, function(res) {
  res.pipe(file);
});

file.on('close', function() {
  exec('update_setup.exe', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
    // output from starting
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank-you ... this works. Once my app is packaged, where is this file getting downloaded to?

Comment: The file downloads to the path you specify in `fs.createWriteStream()`. If you don't specify any paths, it downloads the the directory the script was executed in.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Would it be possible to display a progess bar for the download?

Comment: If you wanted to display a progress bar, you would have to use `res.on('data', function(chunk) {});` and compare the amount of received data to the `Content-Length` header you receive from the server.

Comment: Congrats on the unsung hero badge! :)